# I was running the default flutter code on android studio, and this error came up saying something about license agreement

Tags: android-studio, flutter, exception

I just installed android studio and flutter on my laptop, and i was running the default code to test my settings, but this error(exception) came up. I am very new to this, can someone help me with this error please -

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\Shreyansh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Shreyansh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
> platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Shreyansh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: So, did you "accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager"?

Answer (score 0):

- Open your Android Studio
- Open the "Tools" menu
- Select "SDK Manager"

In the following screen, make sure API Level 28 says "Installed".

If it doesn't, install it. You will have to agree to the license agreement.