# Checking the license for Android SDK

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> tools Android SDK Tools
> build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool:
> sdkmanager --licenses
> Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 59s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

that they code would run

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a similar problem discussed in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356544/i-was-running-the-default-flutter-code-on-android-studio-and-this-error-came-up).

Can you please check an [answer stated there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63356755/21251815), with the only difference in *API Level 30*?